# 2D overlay on top of 3D plane with texture

Tags: three.js, 2d, overlay

I am trying to draw a 2D square on top of my plane but I can not get to a good solution. So far I just draw 3D lines on top of the plane.

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(HANDLES[0].position.x, HANDLES[0].position.y, HANDLES[0].position.z));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(HANDLES[0].position.x, HANDLES[1].position.y, HANDLES[0].position.z));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(HANDLES[0].position.x, HANDLES[1].position.y, HANDLES[1].position.z));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(HANDLES[0].position.x, HANDLES[0].position.y, HANDLES[1].position.z));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(HANDLES[0].position.x, HANDLES[0].position.y, HANDLES[0].position.z));

material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { 
  color: 0xff00f0,
  linewidth: 20 } );

line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

The result does not look good as the line is mixed up with the texture.

Which would be the best way to draw a net 2D shape on top of a plane? I then want to use this 2D shape to select a region of interest in the plane.

I guess a solution would be to use a orthographic camera + a box somehow but I would like to avoid that if possible.

[image] [image]

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent z-fighting ( coplanar [on the same plane] objects getting mixed up ) you can either set one of the objects as transparent with opacity 1.0 ( hacky but easy approach ) or you can set the `.polygonOffset`, `polygonOffsetFactor`and `polygonOffsetUnits` on the material ( setting both to 1.0 should easily sort this out ), but feel free to [read more about it](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm).

Comment: thanks, see also: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2593 https://github.com/benpurdy/threejs-decals